# Three screens with vertical sliding ability

Tags: java, android, screen, slide

How is the best way to make three vertical screens with sliding between them, like ViewPager.

I want to show user middle screen with ViewPager for horizontal pictures sliding, and two screens for settings (top and bottom).

I tried to use ViewPager in ViewPager, but it's a bad solution for me.
Then ViewFlipper but could not make sliding between screens like ViewPager.
My last chance now is ViewDragHelper but I'm not sure.

Maybe somebody knows real example?

[image]

Comment: A rough diagram or UI prototype might help us to understand what you want and then suggest suitable components

Comment: add diagram to question